# How to get a specific path with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am very new using powershell, I would like to do the following script:

```
Copy-Item -Path args[0]\index.html -Destination args[0]\print.html
Get-Content args[0]\print.html | %{$_ -replace "root","print"}
```

What I want to do is to make a copy of `index.html` and call it `print.html`.
then I want to get the content of that `print.html` (at the same path as above) and replace all "root" for "print".

The problem I have is that PowerShell doesn't recognize args[0] with `Get-Content`, so I need a way to pass that path dynamically and not hardcoded as the path might change depending of the user.

This is the error:

```
Get-Content : An object at the specified path args[0]\print.html does not
exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.
At C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\officine\prepare-print-page.ps1:2 char:1
+ Get-Content args[0]\print.html | %{$_ -replace "root","print"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.String[]:String[]) [Get-Content], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

---

Update:

OK, sorry I was not very clear, I have seen other stackoverflow post and I found about param so now my script look like this:

```
param ([string]$path)
Copy-Item $path\index.html -Destination $path\print.html
Get-Content $path\print.html | %{$_ -replace "root","print"}
```

and on my js file when I build my app I pass the argument like this:

```
`prepare-print-page.ps1 ${outputPath}`
```

the outputPath variable holds the path where the index.html is, which looks like this: C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\myapp\build

but it not copying and creating the print.html, I am basically trying to do the same as this bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Duplicate the index page (which contains all the React scripts) and
# rename the id of the main element from "root" to "print". index.jsx
# will then render the correct component.

echo "Generating print.html in directory $1 ..."
cp $1/index.html $1/print.html
sed -i.bak 's/id="root"/id="print"/g' $1/print.html
rm $1/print.html.bak
```

Comment: Where have you copied this code from? [grin]

Comment: how are you getting info into `$Args`?

Comment: Do you have a literal path `C:\some\folder\args[0]\print.html`? Or do you want to invoke `Get-Content` with a value from an argument?

Comment: I updated my post, sorry I wasn't clear enough

Comment: What js file? What app? If you're trying to invoke a PowerShell script from a non-PowerShell environment please provide more details about that environment. Is the PowerShell script being run at all? What is the actual value that is passed to the script parameter? Try adding a line `"-${path}-" > C:\Windows\Temp\output.txt` to the PowerShell script (right after the parameter definition). Is that file being created? What is its content?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an array with arguments called $args. 
You should access the value of the array $args by addressing it with the $ sign

```
     $args[0]\index.html
```

will retrieve the value of the first entry in the array and add it to your path

Further documentation about_Arrays from microsoft technet:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-6

I think that if you want to work with params you have to create a function:
This should do what you want to achieve:

```
    function prepare-print-page {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true
        )][String]$path)
        $content= Get-Content "$path\index.html" | %{$_ -replace "root","print"} 
        $content > $path\print.html
    }
```

To call the function paste it into your powershell and call it:

```
prepare-print-page "C:\Temp"
```